# Python typing for a subclass of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, subclass, python-typing

I want to be able to define what the contents of a subclass of list have to be. The class would look like the following.

```
class A(list):
   def __init__(self):
      list.__init__(self)
```

I want to include typing such that the following would happen.

```
import typing

class A(list: typing.List[str]):  # Maybe something like this
   def __init__(self):
      list.__init__(self)

>> a = A()
>> a.append("a")  # No typing error
>> a.append(1)  # Typing error
```

Comment: You want generic types. Note, python *never* enforces your type annotations. You can use third party static type checkers like `mypy` though

Comment: Basically, you need to implement the [`MutableSequence` protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) yourself. I would *not* inherit from `list`, as `A` should be usable anywhere an ordinary `list` is, and that means potentially accepting things like `myAobject.append("foo")`. Have `A` include a `list` as an instance variable instead instead of inheriting from `list`, and let the defined methods enforce the `int`-only restriction.

Comment: (Sorry, I was thinking of list-of-ints in my previous comment.)

Comment: @chepner But if I want all of the same methods as list in my subclass, why not just use list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you post an answer with what you are saying in your comment? I am not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: @Interlooper Say `A` is supposed to be a list of `ints`. The Liskov substitution principle says that anywhere I might want to use an instance of `list`, I should be able to use an instance of `A` in its place. But if `A` is (e.g.) supposed to be a list of `int`s, that means the following is invalid: `a = A(); a.append("foo")`. A `list` is a mutable sequence of arbitrary objects; `A` is not, so it should not be a subclass of `list`. It doesn't matter if the two classes have the same interface, because the semantics are very different.

Comment: @chepner good point.

Comment: I am *asking*, do you understand what type-hints are doing? Are you *using* a third-party type-checker already? You *realize* that type hints don't have runtime effects outside the box?

Comment: @chepner Ahh I see, thanks for taking time to explain this. If I had my subclass inherit from MutableSequence however, would it be right to put an element restriction? If so, how can I code typing declarations such that a type checker could alert malformed appends?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I am using pycharms type checker. It helps my team and I know in other places through our code if the elements are input and dealt with correctly.

Comment: You could, because your class would no longer be a subclass of `list`; it would be its own thing with no assumptions on how it should be used, other than what you yourself define.

Comment: Be sure to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle.

Comment: @chepner Okay, that makes sense. Would you know how I could add the typing restriction using the typing package to define what the elements of my object must be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typing` conveniently provides a generic version of `collections.MutableSequence`, so something to the effect of:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')
class HomogeneousList(typing.MutableSequence[T]):
    def __init__(self, iterable: typing.Iterable[T]=()) -> None:
        self._data: typing.List[T]  = []
        self._data.extend(iterable)

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> T: ...
    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: slice) -> HomogeneousList[T]: ...
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._data[index]

    @typing.overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: int,  item: T) -> None: ...
    @typing.overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: slice, item: typing.Iterable[T]) -> None: ...
    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        self._data[index] = item

    def __delitem__(self, index: typing.Union[int, slice]) -> None:
        del self._data[index]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._data)

    def insert(self, index: int, item: T) -> None:
        self._data.insert(index, item)


string_list = HomogeneousList[str]()
string_list.append('foo')
string_list.append(42)


int_list = HomogeneousList[int]()
int_list.append(42)
int_list.append('foo')
```

Now, `mypy`gives the following errors:

```
test.py:36: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "MutableSequence" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
test.py:41: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "MutableSequence" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

There is some tricky aspects of typing `__getitem__` etc because they accept `slice` objects as well, but not terrible.

Note, this is useful, because if you just try to do:

```
class HomogeneousList(collections.abc.MutableSequence, typing.Generic[T]):
    ....
```

MyPy, at least, doesn't throw an error for append. AFAIKT you'd have to explicitly add:'

```
def append(self, item: T) -> None:
    self._data.append(item)
```

Which sort of removes a lot of the utility of `collections.abc.MutableSequence` to begin with. Anyway, thankfully, typing provides generic versions of all of these out of the box!

Note, you can use these generically, like I've show, but you can also do something like:

```
class StringList(HomogeneousList[str]):
    pass

mylist = StringList([1,2,3]) # mypy error
mylist = StringList('abc') # no error

mylist.append('foo') # no error
mylist.append(42) # mypy error
```

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Python 3.9, you can use:

```py
import typing

class A(typing.List[str]):
    pass
```

This indicates to your type checker that elements of class `A` should be of type `str`. At run-time, this behaves the same as creating a subclass of `list`. [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) specifies how the typing system behaves. In particular, the example in [this section of the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-generic-types-as-base-classes) does something similar to what you're asking, but with `typing.Dict` instead of `typing.List`.

In Python 3.9+, you can [use the built-in type instead of importing from typing](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections). The class becomes:

```py
class A(list[str]):
    pass
```