# Subclass Python list with all elements of the same type

Tags: python, types, subclass, typing

I'm looking for a way to make a subclass of `list` where all elements are of the same type.  I don't need a fully generic implementation, [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913988/python-typing-for-a-subclass-of-list).

What I'd like is something roughly equivalent to the following code (using `typing`):

```py
class NumberParty(list[int]):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        "".join([str(x) for x in self])

    def total(self) -> int:
        return sum(self)
```

The reason I want this class instead of using `List[int]` annotations is that I use the `__str__` method described above in multiple places and want to eliminate the copied lines of code.

---

As a bonus question, would it be wise to overload `__init__` in something similar to the following code?

```py
__init__(self, *numbers: int):
    self = numbers
__init__(self, nums: Iterable[int]):
    self = list(nums)
```

The first way would be for directly creating a new `NumberParty` instance while the second would create one from an existing list or set of integers.

Comment: Bonus answer: no, because assigning to `self` just makes the local name refer to a different object, leaving the actual object untouched.

Comment: So, you want an array? Use a numpy one.

Comment: the only reason I see to override `__init__` or `__new__` is to enforce the same type of members, along with methods that insert members BTW, but if you don't need to enforce that, overriding `__str__` and adding `total` will work just fine

Comment: @Marcos I was hoping to avoid adding too many dependencies to my project: currently, click is the only external dependency.  Would numpy arrays work with more complex datatypes than ints?  The real code would be an array of one type of object.

Comment: @Dalvenjia One of the reasons I want the typing is for the benefit of PyCharm so it can yell at me if I try to add a string to the NumberParty elsewhere in the program and also so that knows that NumberParty[6] is an int without more manually-added type hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, just doing:

```
from typing import List

class NumberParty(List[int]):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "".join([str(x) for x in self])

    def total(self) -> int:
        return sum(self)
```

...should just work.

Note that inheriting from `List[int]` is essentially the same as inheriting from `list` -- the only difference is that type checkers will understand what your custom class is supposed to contain and verify you're using methods like `append(...)` in a type safe way.

However, there is no difference at runtime, and you can still freely ignore your type checker and append strs or whatever, just like how you Python lets you append strs to regular lists that are annotated to be of type List[int].

And since this class is a subtype of List[int], code snippets like the below should type check:

```
def expect_list(x: List[int]) -> None: pass

def expect_number_party(x: NumberParty) -> None: pass

n = NumberParty()

# Both type checks
expect_list(n)
expect_number_party(n)
```

Regarding your question about overriding `__init__` -- you'll need to call the super constructor if you decide to take that route to ensure the class is set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

### Idea

I don't know. If I understood what you asked or not

What I got from your question is: *You want an Array*
As [Marcos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9732470/marcos) said in comments.

And also adding a whole NumPy library to your dependencies for just an array is overkill.

What you need is to make a list-like object which uses a list for storing things and
and a public API and several 'magic functions' for making it work like a list (with the filters you want).

### Code

```py
from typing import Iterable, optional


class NumberParty:
    def __init__(self, iterable: optional[Iterable] = ()):
        self._inner = [].extend(iterable)


    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._inner[item]


    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError("NumberParty only accepts integers")
        self._inner[key] = value


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._inner)


    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._inner)


    def append(self, i: int) -> None:
        if not isinstance(i, int):
            raise ValueError("NumberParty only accepts integers")
        self._inner.append(i)


    def insert(self, index: int, i: int) -> None:
        if not isinstance(i, int):
            raise ValueError("NumberParty only accepts integers")

        self.inner[index] = i


    def extend(self, __iterable: Iterable[int]) -> None:
        # Itering through it to check every value
        for i in __iterable:
            if not isinstance(i, int):
                raise ValueError("NumberParty only accepts integers")
            self.append(i)
```

Please be careful that this `NumberParty` is not complete
Operations like:
`+ - / % * += -= /= %= *=` are not implemented but are implemented in original list (plus several public functions which are not implemented here)

### Tip for completing this `NumberParty` object

This Class can be a wrapper around the `list` object. Waiting for you to complete it ;)

In case you just want type-checkers to show a warning [Michael0x2a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60732405/14294250) works.